# Chaining through class hierarchy wihout calling `super` or inventing new names

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I have methods that use `super`:

```
class A
  def say txt
    puts "A.say from #{self}: #{txt}"
  end
  def run
    puts "A.run from #{self}: I am preparing something here..."
  end
end

class B < A
  def run
    super
    say 'I am B, adding 1'
    say 'I am B, adding 2'
  end
end

class C < A
  def run
    super
    say 'I am C, adding 3'
    say 'I am C, adding 4'
  end
end

class D < C
  def run
    super
    say 'I am D, adding 5'
  end
end
```

I would like to get rid of `super` from the subclasses, and came up with this:

```
class A
  def say txt
    puts "A.say from #{self}: #{txt}"
  end
  def run
    puts "A.run from #{self}: I am preparing something here..."
    run_sub
  end
  def run_sub
    # do nothing by default
  end
end

class B < A
  def run_sub
    say 'I am B, adding 1'
    say 'I am B, adding 2'
  end
end

class C < A
  def run_sub
    say 'I am C, adding 3'
    say 'I am C, adding 4'
    run_sub_sub
  end
  def run_sub_sub
    # do nothing by default
  end
end

class D < C
  def run_sub_sub
    say 'I am D, adding 5'
  end
end
```

Only the leaf classes actually benefit from this. So I thought of keeping the code of the `run` methods as blocks and tried to call them all in order of the class hierarchy. Here's the code:

```
class A
  def say txt
    puts "A.say from #{self}: #{txt}"
  end
  def self.run &block
    @run_block = block
  end
  def self.all_run_blocks
    if self == A
      return [@run_block]
    else
      return superclass.all_run_blocks + [@run_block]
    end
  end
  run do
    puts "A.run from #{self}: I am preparing something here..."
  end
  def run_all
    self.class.all_run_blocks.each do |block|
      block.call unless block.nil?
    end
  end
end

class B < A
  run do
    say 'I am B, adding 1'
    say 'I am B, adding 2'
  end
end

class C < A
  run do
    say 'I am C, adding 3'
    say 'I am C, adding 4'
  end
end

class D < C
  run do
    say 'I am D, adding 5'
  end
end

b = B.new
d = D.new

b.run_all
d.run_all
```

But that didn't work because the blocks passed to the `run` class method remain in the scope of the class, and therefore don't know about the `say` instance method.

Is there a better way to achieve something like this?

Comment: `run_sub` is called a Template Method in pattern lingo; that might help you find some resources on this. I think you're probably on the right track with some kind of metaprogramming. I'd probably write a recursive function to walk up the class hierarchy and execute each superclass method with the same name until the super class no longer has that method defined [self.class.superclass.instance_method(method).bind(self).call]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I want to say this was a really fun problem and I would upvote it again if I could. Thank you for asking a question that actually required some thought and effort and I hope my answer satisfies your requirements.

**Note:** I used your explicit example so this method does not accept arguments. It will take some additional work to handle arguments as well.

Why not make it a `Module` this way you can use it anywhere?

```
module Appendable

  def self.extended(base)
    base.include(InstanceMethods)
  end

  def append_method(method_name,&block)
    alias_name = create_alias(method_name)
    define_method(method_name) do
      run_callbacks(self,alias_name) do |object|
        object.instance_eval &block
      end
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def run_callbacks(object,method_name)
      object.send(method_name)
      yield(self)
    end
  end

  private
    def create_alias(method_name)
      alias_name = "_#{method_name}_callback_#{self.name}"
      alias_method alias_name, method_name
      alias_name
    end
end
```

What this does it is just aliases the original method (`run` in this case) method as `_METHODNAME_callback_CLASSNAME` then redefines the original method to call the aliased version first which creates a recursion up the chain and then `yield`s back to the block given in the class.

Then you just define the classes like so:

```
class A
  extend Appendable

  def run
    say "A"
  end

  def say(txt)
    # I used puts to make it evident that it ran up the chain
    puts "#{self.class.name} said #{txt}"
  end
end
class B < A 
  append_method :run do 
    say "B"
  end
end
class C < B 
  append_method :run do 
    say "C"
  end
end     
class D < A 
  append_method :run do 
    say "D"
  end
end
class E < A
   def run 
     puts "E overwrote run"
   end
end 
class F < E;append_method(:run) { say "F" }; end
```

This will allow all your classes to inherit the previous hierarchical method eg

```
A.new.run
  A said A
B.new.run   
  B said A
  B said B
C.new.run
  C said A
  C said B
  C said C 
D.new.run 
  D said A
  D said D
F.new.run
  E overwrote run
  F said F
```

That seems like the overall affect you were looking for unless I misunderstood?

Answer (score 1):

`Module#prepend` is there precisely for the purpose of doing that:

```
module A
  def say txt
    puts "A.say from #{self}: #{txt}"
  end
  def run
    puts "A.run from #{self}: I am preparing something here..."
    super
  end
end

class B
  prepend A
  def run
    say 'I am B, adding 1'
    say 'I am B, adding 2'
  end
end

class C
  prepend A
  def run
    say 'I am C, adding 3'
    say 'I am C, adding 4'
    super
  end
end

class D
  prepend C
  def run
    say 'I am D, adding 5'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. There are two problems with this code: 1) when "running" `d` (instance of the `D` class), it doesn't call the `C`'s `run` (as in my original code) and 2) the `prepend A` line just replaces the `super` line in my original code so it isn't any shorter.

Comment: I fixed the first problem. Regarding your second point, `prepend A` replaces the necessity of `< A`, so if you insist on short code, you can consider putting it in a single line using a semicolon like `class B; prepend A`. I don't think there is any way better than this.

Comment: Shorting the code was the whole purpose of the exercise :) ...the point is that child classes of `A` should be able to extend the `run` function rather then replace it. That's what I was trying to say by mentioning DSL in my OP (which you deleted when editing it). Classes `B`, `C` and `D` are written by "end users" and should be as short, clean and clear as possible, that's why I came up with the block idea (which unfortunately didn't work). I think @mahemoff's comment is on the right track but I haven't gotten any code from it working just yet.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion in [@mahemoff's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657147/chaining-through-class-hierarchy-wihout-calling-super-or-inventing-new-names/30658179?noredirect=1#comment49378167_30657147) (thank you!), I was able to come up with the following:

```
class A
  def say txt
    puts "A.say from #{self}: #{txt}"
  end
  def run
    puts "A.run from #{self}: I am preparing something here..."
  end
  def run_all
    self.class.ancestors.reverse.each do |ancestor|
      # check if ancestor is a subclass of A
      if ancestor.ancestors.include? A 
        # check if the run method is actually from this ancestor
        if ancestor.instance_method(:run).owner == ancestor
          # call the run method in the context of the given instance
          ancestor.instance_method(:run).bind(self).call
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

class B < A
  def run
    say 'I am B, adding 1'
    say 'I am B, adding 2'
  end
end

class C < A
  def run
    say 'I am C, adding 3'
    say 'I am C, adding 4'
  end
end

class D < C
  def run
    say 'I am D, adding 5'
  end
end

b = B.new
d = D.new

b.run_all
d.run_all
```

This doesn't use a recursive call but rather iterates through the classes' `ancestors` to find their `run` methods and invokes them in sequence.

If you know how that could be improved, please let me know!

Comment: Take a look at the pattern I just posted and let me know if that is what you are looking for or if you want something to change.